# Where is strong-typed HtmlHelper extension method source codes in MVC 2 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I wanted to see source code of HtmlHelper extension methods which takes ExpressionTree parameter but I could not find it in [codeplex.com](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/23011?projectName=aspnet#288011). Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the [source code for ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RTM from here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742). Then look at the `InputExtensions.cs` file.